# connected to wifi but no internet - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I have checked: [Wifi connected but no internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265384/wifi-connected-but-no-internet)
and [Connected to wifi, but no internet [16.04]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820828/connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet-16-04)

`https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028651/wifi-connected-but-cannot-access-internet-ubuntu` --- doesn't work

among other sources....

I've connected to the same network and gotten to the internet on a different computer.  The problem computer is using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and connected to my router. I have an ip address (from wlp1s0). I cannot ping 8.8.8.8. I do not know my ip of my router, i cannot resolve name servers or connect via browser to the internet.

```
user@user-S410G2:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#post-up ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev lo metric 800
```

```
user@user-S410G2:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

```
user@user-S410G2:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

wwp0s20f0u5i12  no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"FRFadmin"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:1E:2A:0A:E7:0A   
          Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:22   Missed beacon:0
```

```
user@user-S410G2:~$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:20:1f:6a:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:d2:52:d1:08:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.130/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 86334sec preferred_lft 86334sec
    inet6 fe80::2d1f:3795:f831:3593/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: wwp0s20f0u5i12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:96:15:9a:e6:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
user@user-S410G2:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4041ms
pipe 3
```

```
user@user-S410G2:~$ sudo lshw -class network 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 78
       serial: d4:d2:52:d1:08:62
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-32-generic firmware=36.9f0a2d68.0 ip=192.168.1.130 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:a9100000-a9101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 00:22:20:1f:6a:85
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:134 memory:a9200000-a921ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wwp0s20f0u5i12
       serial: 9a:96:15:9a:e6:e1
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes
```

the output from various debug /troubleshooting which I seem to gather as being relevant is attached above. This seems to be a prolific problem with Ubuntu.   Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it wifi or ethernet that is causing the issue? Both seem to be connected. The file `/etc/network/interfaces` has been replaced as of Ubuntu 17.10 with netplan. I recommend that you revert your changes to that file and set any details in Network Manager. If you are setting a static IP address, be sure to also include DNS nameservers.

After making any changes, detach the ethernet and restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Does the wifi connect?

```
iwconfig
```

Can you ping the router?

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
```

Can you ping internet nameservers?

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
```

Can you resolve names?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: hi @chili it's wifi.  I don't have hard wire (at this point). Can you explain what you mean by:  "The file /etc/network/interfaces has been replaced as of Ubuntu 17.10 with netplan. I recommend that you revert your changes to that file and set any details in Network Manager."

Comment: You have made a change by editting the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to add a static IP address for the ethernet which you evidently don't even use. Please edit the file once again and remove all of this: # The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
  iface enp0s31f6 inet static
  address 192.168.1.100
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1

Comment: hi chili, that is for another project (robot) maybe i should setup that network connection another way.  anyway, to clean things up for the purposes of getting to the internet, i've reverted that file to remove that connection, restarted the network manager, been unable to connect, though  I no longer have the "?" above my wifi.  I've updated my question with the info you requested and new output of the others.

Comment: How did the wireless get the very interesting IP address?  "ip=192.168.1.130" Did you set a static address in Network Manager? In netplan or some other? I suspect that you omitted DNS nameservers. https://www.itzgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Configure-Static-IP-Address-in-Ubuntu-18.04-Manual-IP-Address-to-WiFi.png

Comment: i awarded you the win chili, because i think it was a conflict with the fixed ip.  oddly, after i changed it ... it didn't work. though since i've been back to the office this week. it's seem to have magically "fixed it self".  unfortunately this question will not likely help anyone else.