# connected to wifi but no internet, network-manager restart temporarily resolves this problem

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

Since some time I am having this issue with my wifi connection. The wifi is connected and I am browsing the internet but the suddenly there is no internet access any more and the wifi symbol shows connected but no internet access. This problem appears randomly sometimes right after start sometimes not at all for hours. The first time when this problem appeared it occurs very rarely. But recently it is happening every 30 seconds.

Every time I get no connection I use the command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

After the network-manager has restarted the connection works again until the connection is lost once more. The intervals of loosing the connection are becoming smaller and smaller. Sometimes I have to restart the manager 10 times in 10 minutes but then suddenly the connection wont break any more and it works for hours.

I have tried a lot of different things from other questions here in this forum but nothing has solved the problem. Other computers in the network do not have this problem.

I don't know how to narrow it down, now. Is there anything I can do to check? This is what I have checked so far:

- When the error occurs, I can not ping ip addresses.
- I have checked
  this but it seems to be another problem:
  [connected to wifi but no internet - ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249398/connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet-ubuntu-18-04#1249420)

Would you recommend to reinstall the network-manager?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What is the wireless hardware? There may be a ton of reasons why a wireless device disconnects. One of the reasons may be that some neighbor is trying to hack your network, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. The wireless hardware is a Wifi Fritz Wlan USB Stick N but I have used another USB device before which had the same problem. Therefore, I thought it is most likely not a hardware or driver problem, especially as it was working fine for a couple of years.
The wired thing is, that the connection seams not to be interrupted, because a video stream will not stop, when it is running. Even if Ubuntu shows "wifi connected but no Internet".
Regarding you assumption of someone trying to hack the network. How can I check that, FirtzBox logs?